# Canadian wife of British citizen, trying to move to Scotland

Tags: uk-visa, canadian-citizens

My husband and I were married last year, while he was in Canada on a vacation visa and, as we do not wish to live apart forever (our relationship was a long distance thing with him visiting me for a few months every year). I am trying to find a way to move to the UK where he lives so we can start a family together.

Unfortunately I've been very confused about the whole application process and we do not have the funds to have a lawyer help us out.

From the www.gov.uk and www.citizensadvice.org.uk websites, I understand that I am trying to apply for a "Family of a settled person visa" but on the www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk site where I was redirected, I wasn't able to find anything called that, so I used the "Family Member of an EEA National" one as it seemed the only thing that fitted.

When I got to the payment section, the button turned green and it was marked "Payment not required". The amount on the payment confirmation section of my form is also marked as 0.00$. It is now making me doubt using the right form.

Has anyone gone through this and has advice, or could help me find resources? My husband called the visa contact center but wasn't able to speak with anyone today and none of the emails I've sent to different places have been answered.

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you've lived together in the EU (but outside the UK) he is not considered an EEA national, so you have to apply for a standard visa: https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa

Comment: Thank you, @SztupY, at least I know I'm going the wrong way about this and there really is a family form. 
Would you happen to know how I can get to it? I was not able to locate it in the drop down menus of the www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk site. Does it have another name?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

> Reason for visit: *settlement*
>
> Visa type: *settlement*
>
> Visa subtype: *wife* or *husband,* as appropriate

Comment: Thank you, @phoog. That is what I thought at first but through https://www.immigrationdirect.co.uk/uk-visas/uk-family-visa.jsp I was led to understand that the first application I need to make is different from the settlement one as I currently am still in Canada, while my husband has gone back to work in the UK.
I also researched the VAF4 form they mention but was then told it is only for applicants from North Korea. This is all very confusing!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fiannae That is correct, but the second application is not a visa application; it must be submitted after you are in the UK.  To enter the UK with the intention of filling an application for leave to remain, you need a settlement visa.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you so much for your help, @phoog. You have been far more helpful than the helplines I have contacted! I will update with results

Comment: They have a form only for applicants from North Korea? That would be amazing.